# Remove grey shadow color of FloatingActionButton with a CardView

Tags: android

This is my layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardview"
        app:elevation="4dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <!-- contents here -->
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/cardview"
        app:elevation="5dp"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="right|bottom">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:elevation="0dp" />

    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I want to remove grey shadow color of FloatingActionButton, I tried with `android:elevation="0dp"`, it removes grey shadow but the entire FloatingActionButton is put behind the CardView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your card view has some default elevation. remove it by adding app:cardElevation="0dp" to your card view and it will work fine

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardview"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <!-- contents here -->
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/cardview"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="right|bottom"/>
```

Comment: It works, but it also remove grey shadow color of CardView. How to not remove it?

Comment: wrap FloatingActionButton inside a transparent framelayout with more elevation than cardview. Let me know if this works

Comment: I edited my question with your suggestion (if I understood correctly), but it doesn't work.

Comment: replace app:elevation="5dp" with android:elevation="5dp" in your framelayout